# Is there a VFH* Implementation for ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am looking for an implementation of the VFH* Algorithm for local obstacle avoidance.
Is there any?

Best regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65491/is-there-a-vfh*-implementation-for-ros?/) by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 230 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you could contact @camilla in this regard. Have a look there: http://answers.ros.org/question/61377/local-planner-creation/

---

Originally posted by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) with karma: 1145 on 2013-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1